# Accessing S3 bucket from local pyspark using assume role

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Background: In order to allow developers to build and unit test code on an easy-to-use environment, we built a local Spark environment with other tools integrated to it. However, we also want to access S3 and Kinesis from Local environment. When we access S3 from Pyspark application from local using assume-role(as per our security standards), it is throwing forbidden error.

FYI - We are below access pattern for accessing resources on AWS account. 
[assume-role access pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9JZB.jpg)

Code for testing  *access-s3-from-pyspark.py* :

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("s3a_test").setMaster("local[1]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sc.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

hadoopConf = {}
iterator = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().iterator()
while iterator.hasNext():
    prop = iterator.next()
    hadoopConf[prop.getKey()] = prop.getValue()
for item in sorted(hadoopConf.items()):
    if "fs.s3" in item[0] :
    print(item)

path="s3a://<your bucket>/test-file.txt"

## read the file for testing
lines = sc.textFile(path)

if lines.isEmpty() == False:
    lines.saveAsTextFile("test-file2.text")
```

Property file *spark-s3.properties*

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key <your access key >
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key <your secret key>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.sts.endpoint sts.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider 
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.session.name testSession1
spark.haeoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.session.duration 3600
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn <role arn>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.canned.acl BucketOwnerFullControl
```

How to run the code:

```
spark-submit --properties-file spark-s3.properties \
        --jars jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar \
        access-s3-from-pyspark.pyenter code here
```

The above code is returning below error, please note I am able to access S3 via CLI and boto3 using assume-role profile or api.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 66FB4D6351898F33, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: J8lZ4qTZ25+a8/R3ZeBTrW5TDHzo98A9iUshbe0/7VcHmiaSXZ5u6fa0TvA3E7ZYvhqXj40tf74=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Questions:

This is right way of doing?

Is there any other easy way to use AWS resources locally for dev and test (I have also explored localstack package which is working most of the cases but still not fully dependable)

Am I using right jars for this?

Comment: Make sure your account does have permission to access object's metadata.

Answer (score 2):

that config of spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider is wrong.

- There should only be one entry and it should list all the AWS credential providers in one single entry
- the S3A assumed role provider (which takes a full login and asks for an assumed role) is only on very recent Hadoop releases (3.1+), not 2.7.x and probably doesn't do what you want. It's mostly used for dynamically creating logins with restricted rights and verifying that the S3A connector itself [can cope with things](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/auth/ITestAssumeRole.java).

It's good that your organisation is strict about security, it just slightly complicates life.

Assuming you can get the account ID, session token and session secret (somehow),

then for Hadoop 2.8+ you can fill in the spark defaults with this

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key AAAIKIAAA
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key ABCD
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fs.s3a.session.token REALLYREALLYLONGVALUE
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider`

You'll need to create those assumed role session secrets for as long as the session last, which used to be PITA as their life was <= 60 minutes; assumed roles can not last for up to 12 hours -your IT team will need to increase the lifespan of any roles you want to use for that long.

The hadoop 2.7.x releases don't have that TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider, so instead you have to

1. Rely on the env var credential provider, which looks up the `AWS_` environment variables. This is enabled by default so you shouldn't need to ply with `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider` at all
2. Set all three of the env vars (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECRET_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` (?)) to those of the values you get from an assumed role API call.
3. Then run your jobs. You'll probably need to set those env vars up everywhere I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Steve Loughran. your answer gives clear idea on which version has the feature that I am looking for. I have done following to resolve: 1) installed Hadoop 2.8.4(it comes with all dependent Jars) and configured spark to use it. 2) configure the credentials in core-site.xml